# Migrating ASP.NET solution from VS 2010 TO VS 2012: error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

When I migrate my ASP.NET solution from VS2010 to VS2012, I get this error  in a dialog window of VS2012:

> error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component

How do I fix that?

Comment: You provided positively no details. What dialog is that? What do you do to have that dialog shown? Is there any callstack for that?

Comment: I just migrate that project from vs 2010 to vs 2012, it can work on vs 2010, but after build and then start without debugging, it pops out a dialog on vs 2012, shows :error hresult e_fail has been returned from a call to a com component. And I checked event viewer of windows, it catches nothing. There is no callstack for that.

Comment: Problem solved. I create a new empty web project, add target project into it, keep the new web.config, adding the original web.config items into the new one step by step. Seems like lacking of new assembly redirection section.